# Uncaught error angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am getting the following error when I try to load my index.html page from localhost8000. Uncaught error angular is not defined on line 2 of main.js page.

Index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' ng-app='App'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src = 'angular/angular.js'></script>
        <script src = 'angular-route/angular-route.js'></script>
        <script src = 'js/main.js'></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ng-view></ng-view> <!-- Allows loading of partials-->
    </body>
</html>

Main.js page:

// Will handle our ng-routes
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute'])

// Configure the partials
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/_ninjas.html', // Allows us to move around and see all the ninjas
    });
});
```

Is there a typo somewhere in my code I am not seeing. I am still attending an online coding bootcamp to learn coding so any tips would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to ensure the angular library load correctly the code seems to be fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    <!-- Allows loading of partials-->
    <script>
  var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute'])

// Configure the partials
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: '<div>Hello</div>', // Allows us to move around and see all the ninjas
    });
});
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

to test your code

Answer (score -1):

That error imples that you do not have angular loaded.

Replace

```
<script src = 'angular/angular.js'></script>
```

with this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

See if it works.